# Changing the "<URL name> says:" header to confirm dialog box

Tags: javascript

When using the confirm dialog box in Javascript, the first line is "<URL name> says:" then it is followed by the string specified in the js call.

Is there a way to change that first line?

Comment: There is no such line in my browser.

Answer (score 1):

The confirm box, just like the alert box, is a system object, and not subject to CSS. To do this style of thing you would need to create an HTML element and mimic the confirm() functionality.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible, the url in the confirm window is not customizable.  As a solution you could create your own modal box and style it as desired.